# How to create a cross validation model for KMeans in C#?

Tags: c#, k-means, cross-validation

I have this code but it gives following error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Accord.MachineLearning.KMeansClusterCollection' to 'Accord.MachineLearning.KMeans'     
error CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**My code :**

```cs
var cv = CrossValidation.Create<KMeans,KMeans,double[],double[]>(

    k: 10, 

    learner: (p) => new KMeans(6),

    loss: (actual, expected, p) => new ZeroOneLoss(expected).Loss(actual),

    fit: (teacher, x , y, w) => teacher.Learn(x),

    x: categoricalInput, y: categoricalOutput
);
```

Comment: P.S. my input and output data are double[][] arrays